# Closing a menu drawer on back button (Safari issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, back-button

I'm trying to close my custom menu drawer when the user clicks the back button.  Right now, this design flaw is the only way a drawer would remain open without hovering.  The desire is that ***only*** hovering can keep a drawer open.

Elaborating:

1 - When you hover the menu, a drawer opens.

2 - When you click a link in the menu (or drawer) thereby leaving the page, the drawer
   will stay open on the page you just left.

3 - When you use the browser's "back" button to return to the page you just left, you'll
   see the menu drawer that was left open.

4 - The only way to close the stuck open menu drawer is to hover & leave it.

I've tried the obvious, which is to utilize the "unload" or "before unload" events.  This is not working because the mouse is still hovering the item when the unload is fired.  The hover is keeping the drawer open while at the same time the unload event is trying to close.  *(I removed broken "unload" function from the demo.)*

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/rNzPR/

Full demo with external links so back button can be tested...

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/rNzPR/show/

Anyway, the result is the same... when clicking the back button, the "last used" menu drawer is stuck open and the only way to close it is to "hover & leave" it again.

I'm interested in suggestions for a workaround so that it does not stick open in the first place or at least so that it does not require a "enter/leave" sequence to get it closed... whichever is more simple.

*(The demo contains borders on transparent containers for development purposes only.  The real system is not that ugly.)*

**EDIT:**

- I am seeing the issue in Safari 4 & 5, and Firefox 3
- In Firefox 4 and 7, the issue occurs but as soon as you move your mouse anywhere in the window, the menu closes.  (good enough)
- I am NOT seeing the issue in IE 8, IE 9, or Chrome.

It seems that certain browsers must be improving or changing how they deal with the "before/after cache" regarding the jQuery `$(document).ready`, because the only way to not have this issue of mine, is for the back button to newly trigger the code within the `$(document).ready`.

Since this looks like mainly just a Safari issue, perhaps I'll live with it for now.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in chrome 14.0.835.202.  Can you elaborate on just what the issue is, and what browsers you can reproduce it in?

Comment: @GeorgePittarelli, I fully updated my question based on your comments.  Thank-you.

Comment: I may be simplifying it, but why not catch the click event on the drawer links, force a drawer close, then let the link proceed (don't return false or preventDefault).

Comment: @BradChristie, I was kinda thinking of something similar but thought it would be the same issue as while catching the `unload` event.  You click (unload) while you're hovering, so the close never occurs.  Yours is the better suggestion since it catches it earlier, so I'll have to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Sparky672: unload was really only supported by IE. Some browsers mimic it, but you can't rely on it in anything but IE.

Comment: @Brad:  Trying to implement your suggestion but now I'm discovering a weird server caching issue.  My old js file is still coming at my url despite being deleted.  I know the path is correct because I can put new files up there... remove them and they still come up in the browser.  Not the browser... I can call up "deleted" file from any browser.  LOL... what a crappy host.

Comment: @Brad, your suggestion seems to be working although it's impossible to tweak it when the server is hanging on to old versions of any *.js file.  Once I settle on the solution, I'll post for others.  Thank-you!

Comment: @Sparky672: Use something like `<script src="myoldjsfile?v=fake.new.version.number">` Adding GET variables to the end forces the browser in to re-grabbing the file (unless it's the host keeping the old version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you should be able to override the behavior my attaching a `closeDrawer` call to the drawer links' click event. Something like:

```
$('div[id|="menu"] a').click(function(){
  // first, close the drawer
  closeDrawer();
  // now just let it carry on with following the link
  // (don't try to return false or event.preventDefault)
});
```

Or, more concisely put:

```
$('div[id|="menu"] a').click(closeDrawer);
```

Comment: I commented earlier as I didn't know if it was an option you'd like to try. But since you seem to be on board, I'll post it as a solution.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working.  I really don't understand this server though.  Even when I delete the entire JS file, I can still call it up in **any** browser.  Caching is one thing but when the file is entirely gone, how can it still get called up?  Goofy as hell.

Comment: I just saw your comment above... it's the host keeping the old version.  I can call it up in a different browser and it's still there even after deletion.